# Angular html extends

Tags: angular

i've got this generic component

**data-list.component.ts**

```
export interface basic_data {name:string}
@Component({
  selector: 'data-list',
  templateUrl: './data-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-list.component.scss'],
})
export class DataListComponent {

    public data: basic_data[] = [];
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

**data-list.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <label>{{item.name}}</label>
<div>
```

I'd like to extend DataListComponent in order to display differents information depending on the type of data.

```
export interface ext_data extends basic_data {ext_value:string}
export class Ext_DataListComponent extends DataListComponent {

    public ext_data: ext_data[] = [];
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.data = this.ext_data;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to inherit the html as well so i can display the ext_data?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <label>{{item.name}}</label>
    <label>{{item.ext_value}}</label>
<div>
```

I really don't want to copy/past the entire tempate page and logic

Comment: you can add `data-list.component` as a child to `Ext_DataListComponent ` , so you don't need to rewrite the code

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice to extend the component, and the template cannot be extended.
Use the inputs to do this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'data-list',
  templateUrl: './data-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-list.component.scss'],
})
export class DataListComponent {
    @Input() data: basic_data[];
    @Input() isShowExt = false;
}

<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <label>{{item.name}}</label>
    <label *ngIf="isShowExt">{{item.ext_value}}</label>
</div>
```

Example 1:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example1',
  templateUrl: './example1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example1.component.scss'],
})
export class Example1 {
    data = [
      { name: 'test_name' },
      { name: 'test_name' },
      { name: 'test_name' },
    ]
}

<data-list [data]="data"></data-list>
```

Example 2:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example2',
  templateUrl: './example2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example2.component.scss'],
})
export class Example2 {
    data = [
      { name: 'test_name', ext_value: 'value' },
      { name: 'test_name', ext_value: 'value' },
      { name: 'test_name', ext_value: 'value' },
    ]
}

<data-list [data]="data" [isShowExt]="true"></data-list>
```

Comment: bad practice? What are we supposed to do? Copy/past?

Comment: You can use a sub component to show the data in a different way. You could switch between components using the ngSwith directive.

Comment: @Bastok because the decorators do not extends

Comment: @Chris, and why should it be a problem? Ok inheritance might be a bad practice for some reasons, but copy/pasting is the worst solution ever.

Comment: @Bastok but where will you see in the implementation above copy/paste

Comment: @Chris, may bad. When i wrote my previous comment i haven't seen it. But this solution is not even close to "good practice".

Comment: @Bastok why do you think this?

Comment: @Chris because, a parent should never be aware of any inherited children. This is the very basic of OOP

Comment: @Bastok then for what are angular inputs?

Comment: Inputs are just a way to pass parameters to a component, there is nothing to do with OOP. And composition IS a way to do OOP.

Comment: @Bastok in angular it is used more Composition than OOP